# how to convert the unstructured data to structured data using pandas

Tags: json, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have a bunch of huge sensor data which is in excel file the data something looks like json format(not exactly)need to parse the data i dont have any idea the data something looks like this
`FM4 [Priority=0] [GPS element=[X=776517049] [Y=128887449] [Speed=4] [Angle=102] [Altitude=900] [Satellites=8]] [IO=[239=1] [240=1] [80=1] [21=5] [200=0] [69=1] [1=1] [179=0] [2=1] [180=0] [113=99] [841=0] [842=0] [181=14] [182=10] [66=12087] [24=4] [205=28441] [206=31908] [67=4117] [68=0] [9=12157] [17=-152] [18=0] [19=123] [6=-21015] [241=40486] [800=12087] [840=44496] [14=4619303992] [11=899186004] ] [Timestamp=1666676090000] [EventSource=0] [IMEI = 357544375160179]:::5548###[[IMEI = 357544375160179],[Latitude = 128887449],[Longitude = 776517049],[Speed = 4],[Angle = 102],[Altitude = 900],[Odometer = 0],[IO = [Power = 0] [Digital Input 1 = 1] [Digital Input 2 = 1] [Battery Current = 0] [Analog Input 2 = 44521] [Sleep Mode = 0] [Analog Input 1 = 12157] [ICCID = 899186004] [ICCID2 = 4619303992] [Axis X = -152] [Asis Y = 0] [Asis Z = 123] [Data Mode = 1] [PDOP = 14] [Speed = 4] [External Voltage = 12087] [Battery Voltage = 4117] [GSM Signal = 5] [GPS Validity = 1] [Battery Percentage = 99] [Ignition = 1] [Movement = 1] [Active GSM Operator = 40486] [Digital Output 1 = 0] [Digital Output 2 = 0] [Voltage = 12087] ]]######Device Time : 2022-10-25 05:34:50, Time Zone Of Device Set On System : Plus 00:00###` this is only one row data
and expected output is
[image]
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p4CgX1ZLQVgAOOAw8cBUtQ5p3RwFfci4hcsf7oPB-qE/edit?usp=sharing this is my piece of data first 12 columns are formatted correctly and 13 column data is merged and not able to parse the data how to do it in python.

how to do this by using python

Comment: can you share a sample file that you have initially?

Comment: How to share here

Comment: you can upload it to google drive and share the link to that file.

Comment: What you posted is not clear on line breaks. Can you dump content to pastebin.com?

Comment: Unable to share the data due to privacy concern anyway one entire row data I pasted above kindly check

Comment: shared google drive link to the data

Comment: Shared Google drive data can any one look on to it

Comment: @AshutoshYadav shared link above

Comment: @AparnaAppu The sheet that u have shared is the raw data you are getting initially Right? now can you show a sample of what output you are trying to achieve?  for that, you can create a new sheet in the same file and make the data as you are expecting. It will help me to understand the requirement.

Comment: Pasted screenshot above you can see the picture which I parsed manually without coding

Answer (score -1):

First download your file and save it as .csv (Comma Separated Value) through the Excel.
Then import pandas library by writing:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Then read this file and convert it to DataFrame as follows:

```
data=pd.read_csv('yourfilename.csv')
```

Now you have a tabular data that you can analyse easily!